# para / por in the same context

Tags: preposiciones

I have the following sentence:

"Él trabaja **para** ganarse la vida, yo en cambio lo hago **por** amor al arte"

To my understanding, the second part of the sentence is in the same context as the first, therefore it should be para as well in that situation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sentence, "para" is *in order to*, and "por" is *for the sake of*.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, so in the first example I'm working towards the goal of earning a living (ganarse la vida) while in the second one I work because of my passion for art (which would be a cause)?

Comment: @MikeHeimlich - Correct.  The second part is explaining why you get up in the morning.

Comment: Closely related to this are the two questions:  ??por qué?  And ??para qué?  Both are often translated as "why?" But they are very different  questions.